# how to add contact to DL

Tags: active-directory, directory

any one can help me to add a contact to Distributin list in Active directory.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

What's your problem in doing it? Active Directory fully supports adding contacts to DLs.

If you just can't find it in the search box, add "contacts" to "object types" before searching.

Answer (score 1):

From outlook you should be able to edit the DL through the addressbook (click 'Modify Members').

From the commandline you could do:

```
NET GROUP /DOMAIN <distribution list alias> /ADD <userID>
```